# Unable to overload submit method of Ajax.BeginForm

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I'm trying to submit an ajax form from my razor view, and I want the controller to return a JSON object. When I use ("#form0").submit(alert("hi");); the data goes to the controller and I get an alert. However, when I use ("#form0").submit(function(){alert("hi");}); the data does not get passed, and I do not get an alert. I get the feeling that this is something minor with my syntax that I'm missing. Here's the relevant code:

jquery:

```
$(function () {
//setting up the schedule modal dialoag.
$("#schedModal").dialog({
    buttons: {
        Submit:
                function () {
                    $("#form0").ajaxSubmit(function () {
                        //this is where I want to put the magic, but I need the alert to fire first.
                        alert("hi");
                        return false;
                    });
                },
        Cancel:
                function () {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
    },
    autoOpen: false,
    minHeight: 350,
    modal: true,
    resizable: false
});
```

the targeted view:

```
@model FSDS.DataModels.Schedule

@using (Ajax.BeginForm("scheduleNew", null, new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "partial" }, new {}))
{
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ScheduleName)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ScheduleName)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ScheduleName)
    </div>

    @* tons of other labels and editor fields go in here, omitted for brevity. *@
}
```

The controller, if that matters:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult scheduleNew(Schedule schedule)
    {
        if (Request.HttpMethod == "POST")
        {
            FSDSDBEntities context = new FSDSDBEntities();

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                context.Schedules.AddObject(schedule);
                context.SaveChanges();
            }

            return Json(schedule);
        }
        else
        {
            return PartialView();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use `$('#form0').submit();`:

```
Submit: function () {
    $('#form0').submit();
}
```

Then define an `OnSuccess` handler in your AjaxForm that will be invoked when the AJAX request succeeds:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("scheduleNew", null, new AjaxOptions { OnSuccess = "success", UpdateTargetId = "partial" }, new {}))
```

and finally `success` javascript handler:

```
function success(data) {
    // the form was successfully submitted using an AJAX call.
    // here you could test whether the data parameter
    // represents a JSON object or a partial view
    if (data.ScheduleName) {
        // the controller action returned the schedule JSON object
        // => act accordingly
    } else {
        // the controller action returned a partial view
        // => act accordingly
    }
}
```

Comment: Works like a dream. You are a gentleman and a scholar, Darin Dimitrov.